# Loop through read only .zip data archive to extract line from .kml file within

Tags: bash, zip, xml, readonly

I am trying to access some satellite data on a read only archive. I am only interested in files with certain co-ordinates listed in a .xml within the zip that match my research area.

There are multiple files per day of the year. Currently I am focusing on a folder 2015/07. This has a separate folder for each day of the month in it. Each day folder contains lots of .zip files and other file types.

The naming convention/structure of the zip files is always the same so that the .zip file name is used in all of it’s contained files – with the suffixes/file extensions changing like below:

```
$unzip -l S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.zip                                                                                                     Archive:  S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/
    16099  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/manifest.safe
        0  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/measurement/
861899961  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/measurement/s1a-iw-grd-vv-20150701t135110-20150701t135135-006618-008d39-001.tiff
        0  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/annotation/
  1685172  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/annotation/s1a-iw-grd-vv-20150701t135110-20150701t135135-006618-008d39-001.xml
        0  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/annotation/calibration/
  1013267  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/annotation/calibration/calibration-s1a-iw-grd-vv-20150701t135110-20150701t135135-006618-008d39-001.xml
   317418  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/annotation/calibration/noise-s1a-iw-grd-vv-20150701t135110-20150701t135135-006618-008d39-001.xml
        0  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/
     2437  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/product-preview.html
   124584  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/quick-look.png
        0  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/icons/
    95280  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/icons/logo.png
     1026  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/map-overlay.kml
    20088  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE-report-20150701T155156.pdf
        0  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/
      440  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-product-preview.xsd
      450  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-map-overlay.xsd
      471  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-level-1-measurement.xsd
    62654  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-object-types.xsd
      469  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-level-1-quicklook.xsd
     6427  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-level-1-calibration.xsd
   147222  07-08-2015 15:04   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-level-1-product.xsd
     3956  07-08-2015 15:05   S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/support/s1-level-1-noise.xsd
```

.So if I chose one day of the month I can check each the coordinates in each .kml file using:

```
unzip -p  S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.zip S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20150701T135110_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE/preview/map-overlay.kml`
```

To give the contents of the whole .kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>0_20150701T135135_006618_008D39_BE79.SAFE<kml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://wwsa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1" xmlns:s1sar="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentia.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar/level-2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com
  <Document>
    <name>Sentinel-1 Map Overlay</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Sentinel-1 Scene Overlay</name>
      <GroundOverlay>
        <name>Sentinel-1 Image Overlay</name>
        <Icon>
          <href>quick-look.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <gx:LatLonQuad>
          <coordinates>-115.928909,35.970608 -118.750404,36.374107 -118.459686,
        </gx:LatLonQuad>
      </GroundOverlay>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

However, I need to do this for every day of 2015 and 2016 so what I would like to do is:
Loop through the zip files and print the name of the .zip file and the line from the contained .xml file which has the co-ordinates in it:

```
<coordinates>-115.928909,35.970608 -118.750404,36.374107 -118.459686,
    </gx:LatLonQuad>
```

I don’t expect anyone to completely write this for me but a bit of help starting off would be helpful.

Comment: So, which part is unclear?

Comment: How to start doing this as an automated/loop process rather than checking each day .zip file manually @MichaelVehrs

Comment: As in, `find DIR -name "*201607*.zip" | xargs some_command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with something like this:

```
for zf in *.zip ; do
  base=${zf/\.zip/}

  echo "$zf"

  unzip -p "$zf" "$base.SAFE/preview/map-overlay.kml" | 
    sed -ne '/<gx:/,/<\/gx:/p'

done
```

This pipes the .../map-overlay.kml file from each .zip file into `sed`, which prints only the lines between `<gx:` and `</gx:`.

Alternatively, if you only want the `<coordinates>` line, change the `sed` script to:

```
sed -ne '/<coordinates>/p'
```

Note, however, that while these `sed` scripts work with your sample data, even a simple extraction of a few lines from an XML file is prone to failure if you use regular expressions to do the extraction.  It would be remiss of me not to say:

Don't parse XML or HTML [with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). Here's why it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158).

Using `xmlstarlet` would be better.  A `perl` or `python` script, using one of their XML-parsing libraries would be even better. BTW, both `perl` and `python` also have library modules for working with .zip files....so the whole job could be done in either of those languages.

Comment: Thank you @cas. I was wondering whether python might be a better option so thanks for the confirmation.